# Opening documents with Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsdocument

I have the following method to open documents.

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[editorView setString:stringData];

if ( outError != NULL ) {
    *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:unimpErr userInfo:NULL];
}

return YES;
}
```

It seems though that the document and its views are not loaded until `YES` is returned so I cant set the content of the text view because its not yet loaded. Does any one know of a work around for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoa follows the model-view-controller (MVC) design pattern. You should read up on it [in the conceptual documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

Don't store your model information in your view. That is, your document object should hold the contents of the loaded file (in an instance variable). Later, <del>when</del> *if* -windowControllerDidLoadNib is called (signifying a copy of the document UI has been loaded for the document), you can update your view with the file's contents.

NSDocument's approach is useful because there are a number of circumstances under which you might want to instantiate the document but not its UI (think scripting, importing, Spotlight importer querying, instant printing, ...).